# Flask request.url doesn't tell me the port number?

Tags: python, flask

We're using Python.

Flask's `request.url` returns me the entire URL of the request, except the port number is missing.  For example, if our front end invokes

`GET https://my.domain:1024/this/is/my/url`

Then `request.url` gives me

`https://my.domain/this/is/my/url`

Did I do something wrong or is the port somehow consumed by the mysteries of uwsgi and flask?

Comment: Your port is where uWSGI (actually, the socket server underneath, or a web server forwarding to it) waits for connections which are then funneled to Python/Flask - from Flask's perspective, in this case, there is no port to speak of.

Comment: @zwer I suspected as much. Thank you